# The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process. error after publishing mvc6 to cloud

Tags: publish, asp.net-core-mvc

I just created a new ASP5 MVC6 project using visual studio 2015 "web application- No Authentication" **templete** project. I didn't make any changes to the project and I published the project on local and uploaded the published files to the host (gearhost.com) using Filezilla. But when I open my site it gives me this error:
The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.

My website address:
http://publish1.gear.host/

Here is what **web.config** contains:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*"     modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="..\approot\web.cmd" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="..\logs\stdout.log" startupTimeLimit="3600"></httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here is what **launchSettings.json** contains:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:26153/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "Hosting:Environment": "Development"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "commandName": "web",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "Hosting:Environment": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is what **global.json** contains:

```
{
  "projects": [
    "src"
  ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },
  "packages": "packages"
}
```

Here is what **appsettings.json** contains:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Verbose",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks..

Comment: Does the host have IISPlatformHandler installed? Is it v1.2? Do they have the right version installed? (32 v 64bit).

Basically this looks like a host problem, not something you can fix. Ask your host to look at the IIS platform handler logs, and go through https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1000

As an aside don't set Development as your hosting environment on a live server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not support .NET 5 or MVC 6 just yet as they are not in release (only beta/rc). We do however support all versions of .NET and MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Few considerations:

1. Your host needs to have httpPlaformHandler module installed for this to work.
2. Do you know if you host supports ASP.NET Core?
3. Error seems to suggest that the handler was not able to serve the request properly. You can do `stdoutLogEnabled ="true"` in the web.config and see the actual reason for the failure in the log file. Could be because of permissions, EF not able to talk to DB server, could be the DNX process path is not found.